# Using Bootstrap Select For Multiple Select Not Working Properlly

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-select

I am using BootStrap-Select for multi-selection purpose.If i have 10 options and I select 3 or more options and now going to select a 4th one then the other selected option unselect randomly. I am using bootstrap select following functions:

```
$('#deptID').selectpicker('refresh');
$('#'+entry).prop('disabled',false);
```

[BootStrap-Select Reference](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/)

Select

```
<select id="years" class="select" data-live-search="true" class="selectpicker col-md-12" onchange="change_in_year()" multiple>
<option id="2011" value="2011">2011</option>
<option id="2012" value="2012">2012</option>
<option id="2013" value="2013">2013</option>
<option id="2014" value="2014">2014</option>
<option id="2015" value="2015">2015</option>
<option id="2016" value="2016">2016</option>
<option id="2017" value="2017">2017</option>
<option id="2018" value="2018">2018</option>
</select>
```

change_in_year()

```
change_in_year()
{
var yearSelect = new Array();
var i = 0;


$("#years option:selected").each(function(){
        yearSelect[i] = $(this).val();
        i++;
});

var yearS = new Array();
var i = 0;

$("#years option").each(function(){
        yearS[i] = $(this).val();
        i++;
});

if(yearSelect[0] == 0)
{


        yearS.forEach(function(entry) {
            if(entry != "0")
            {
            $('#'+entry).prop('disabled',true);
            $('#'+entry).prop('selected',false);
            }
        });
        $('#years').selectpicker('refresh');
}
if( (yearSelect[0] != 0) )
{

        yearS.forEach(function(entry) {
            $('#'+entry).prop('disabled',false);
        });
        $('#years').selectpicker('refresh');
}   
}
```

this is the actual working code same as mine and working properly in jsFiddle. But on my system selecting option cause deselection of other selected options

[jsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/nagnambi154/g24gp/2/)

Comment: Can you please provide some more code or create a jsfiddle.

Comment: added the code which use the bootstrap-select

Comment: Seems to work fine (http://bootply.com/106018), but where is your code that initializes the select on `#years`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Above Work Fine On JSFiddle. I Changed the jquery.js and bootstrap.js. Now its work Fine in my system also..